# Row Overflow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```dart
  SizedBox(
                    height: size.height * 0.5,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: size.height * 0.5,
                            child: Card(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 5, 10),
                              key: _cardKey,
                              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),
                              elevation: 10.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                  CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                  children: _numbers.map((int number) {
                                    counter++;
                                    return CustomPaint(
                                      painter: BarPainter(
                                        width: cardSize!.width / sample,
                                        height: number,
                                        index: counter,
                                        size: cardSize,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

I want the Row to be constrained inside the card, but it overflows, can anyone suggest why is this happening? Here is a picture of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet without depending on others' data like here `BarPainter` etc

Comment: that does look suspiciously like you are trying to visualize sorting algorythms :D

Comment: @YeasinSheikh which code-snippet do you want? The Bar Painter is just wrapped inside a row

Comment: @MindStudio yes, that's what I'm upto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in this issue [flutter issue #31202](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31202) The CustomPainter can draw outside the canvas. One way you could limit this is by checking that the coordinates of the stuff you draw are inside the canvas.

Second method would be to wrap the `CustomPaint` inside a `ClipRect` to cut off everything outside the widgets boundary.

**Edit:** I just realised that you are using an individual painter for every line. I would use one painter/canvas for all lines that iterates over all numbers and draws the bars at once. This would also increase performance I guess.

Comment: Adding clipRect in canvas proved to work fine and thanks for suggesting looping the canvas, it actually improved performance